# How to cancel Firebase Realtime Database ongoing write or delete operation in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a chat app, and like Whatsapp, I need to provide users the facility to save their messages as undelivered when internet connectivity is OFF, and as soon as the internet is back then that data should be **retried to be sent to the receiver**.

But, in case I scheduled a write operation using Firebase *.setValue()*, then how could I cancel that process in case the user changes his mind and doesn't want that message to be sent, or in technical terms does not want to **setValue()**, how could I stop that ongoing write.

Comment: Why not simply remove the value, right after was set?

Comment: is this the most efficient way of doing it?

Comment: As far as I see, the [setValue()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#setValue(java.lang.Object)) method returns a [Task<Void>](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html) object and I don't see any cancel method in that class.

Comment: there may be a little chance that the internet may become unavailable between setting value and removing it then(although its less probable to happen).

Comment: Yes, that's certainly possible. However, when the device regains connection, the message will be deleted.

Comment: "when the device regains connection, the message will be deleted" , that could be done, but by the time the message isn't deleted the receiver may see the message which makes the purpose of deleting the message useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand from your scenario, the problem arises when the device is offline and you want to let the user the possibility to delete the message, so it cannot be displayed once it regains connectivity. Because the [setValue()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#setValue(java.lang.Object)) method returns a [`Task<Void>`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html) object and because I don't see any cancel method in this class, the only thing to do it to simply remove the message. In this case, when the user is back online, no other users will see the deleted message.

On the other side, it's true that there is a chance in which the user sends the message and right after that he loses connectivity. Even if there was a cancel method, you would have nothing to cancel, as the message is already set on the server. Again, the single option that you have is to delete the message. The delete operation will remain in queue until the device regains connectivity and right after the synchronization the message will be deleted.

Besides that, remember to set the persistence enabled, because it's not enabled by default:

```
setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

Comment: you are right in that case, but for me there is no need to use **setPersistenceEnabled(true)** because I am already using Room library to store messages offline

Comment: Ok, good to hear that. I mentioned that in the case of Firebase. Thanks

Comment: so what is your opinion about using  **purgeOutstandingWrites ()** , I just found it kind of useful, although it would delete all the pending messages for all the users from Firebase Cache Queue.

Comment: If it deletes all messages, it means that don't have control over individual messages. So if you write for example 10 messages while offline and you want to delete a single one, you delete all 10? What happens with the other 9? You should write them again?

Comment: Nope, that won't be efficient so I just dropped this idea, and moved to something like Facebook Messenger, where if you delete any unsent message than that message would be deleted from your your side but as soon as your internet connectivity is ON again then that message is resent, but in case you deleted any unsent message and then restarted the Messenger app then that message won't be sent again or won't be retried to be sent.

Comment: Anyways i have another question to ask about my chat app, see ya soon there :)